# Merging Country name with respect to Country code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframe with df1 and df2 , df1 contains column Country code and Country name , df2 contains column Name , dept , Country Code. I want to add Country name from df1 to df2 with respect to Country Code.
Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

if they have organised records, this should work

```
df2.country = df1.country
```

Comment: The data is not organised